# C# WPF проблема с CheckBox событием IsChecked = true;

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть кусок кода, который снимает галочку с `CheckBox1`:

```
CheckBox1.IsChecked = false;
```

Есть событие `CheckBox1_Unchecked` которое реагирует на то, когда галочка снимается кодом:

```
private void CheckBox1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      // Тут код
}
```

Как избежать этого?

Comment: Если что я долго до этого доходил, но всё привело именно к этому. Стоит убрать CheckBox1.IsChecked = false как код начинает прекрасно работать. Но стоит добавить, вместе с кодом срабатывает событие CheckBox1_Uncheked

Comment: Отписывайтесь от события перед снятием галочки и подписывайтесь после снятия. А вообще вы занимаетесь строительством велосипеда, изучите уже наконец MVVM, чтобы не хакерить

Comment: Не помогает. И по всей видимости дело не в этом..

Answer (score 1):

А зачем избегать? Выставьте флаг, который будет сообщать, что галочка снимается.

```
bool IsModifyingCheckbox = false;
private void CheckBox1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsModifyingCheckbox)
        return;
    // Тут код
}
```

```
bool oldState = IsModifyingCheckbox;
try
{
    IsModifyingCheckbox = true;
    checkBox.Checked = false;
}
finally
{
    IsModifyingCheckbox = oldState;
}
```

Но лучше перейдите на MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

Избежать чего, штатного срабатывания функции-обработчика на событие? о_О никак, только "отцепить" обработчик от события (см. коммент Андрея).

Если хочешь, чтобы код прописанный в обработчике выполнялся только на действия пользователя, а на программные манипуляции нет -- пишем его в обработчик Click'а по элементу и внутри проверяем isChecked, например.